# GSpread error when inserting to Google Sheet: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

i have the following functions:

```
import os,sys
import configparser
from mystrings import *
from mypandas import *
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gd
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    
def send_data_gsheet(file_id,worksheet_name,df,mode='a'):
            gc = gspread_connect()
            sh = gc.open_by_key(file_id)
            ws = None
        
        try:
            ws = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name)
        except: #create worksheet if worksheet isn't exist
            print("Worksheet '{}' is not found. Creating one...".format(worksheet_name))
            sh.add_worksheet(worksheet_name,1000,1000)
            ws = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name)
            print("Worksheet '{}' created.".format(worksheet_name))
        print_text_line(1,"Current worksheet is: '{}'".format(ws.title))
           
        if(mode=='w'):
            ws.clear()
            gd.set_with_dataframe(worksheet=ws,dataframe=df,include_index=False,include_column_header=True,resize=True)
            return True
        elif(mode=='a'):
            ws.add_rows(df.shape[0])
            gd.set_with_dataframe(worksheet=ws
                                  ,dataframe=df
                                  ,include_index=False
                                  ,include_column_header=False
                                  ,row=ws.row_count+1
                                  ,resize=False)
            return True
        return False
```

I am able to connect with `gspread`. In the functions above i want  to send dataframes to Google Sheets and create a sheet automatically if worksheet is not found. I am able to call the functions using the following commands:

```
send_data_gsheet(file_id = '1qDdOpKoYQ5R4VlP612_T845RJyQni2-V9IuJ676E07c'
                 ,worksheet_name='brand2'
                 ,df=df
                 ,mode='w')
```

I am also able to create the new file using `add_worksheet()`.
Now i am wondering why wouldn't it send the dataframes into Google Sheet?
it returned the following error:

> Out of range float values are not JSON compliant

How do i resolve this?

Update:
My top 5 dataframe:

```
Brand
0   A Plus
1   A Plus G-Strength
2   A Tube
3   A1 (A One)
4   AA
```

Replicate:

here's my `gspread_connect` function:

```
def gspread_connect():
    gc = None
    json_key = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())+'\\keyz\gsheet-automations-383508-f832c5a2f142.json'
    print("json key: {}".format(json_key))    
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    if os.path.exists(json_key):
        print_text_line(1,"json key exists. Creating credentials...")
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_key, scope)
        print_text_line(1,"credentials created. Authorizing GSpread...")
        try:
            gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
            print('Gspread authorized')
        except Exception as e:
            print_text_line(1,"Authorization with gspread failed.\n{}".format(e))
    else:
        print_text_line(1,'Failed to get credentials. Key is not found.\nLocation: {}'.format(json_key))
    return gc
```

here's my `get_data_gsheet` function:

```
def get_data_gsheet(file_id,worksheet_name):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        gc = gspread_connect()
        sh = gc.open_by_key(file_id)
        try:
            ws = sh.worksheet(worksheet_name)
            print_text_line(1,"Getting data from '{}' in '{}'...".format(worksheet_name,file_id))
            data = ws.get_all_records()
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            print("Getting data completed.\n Total row: {} row(s)".format(df.shape[0]))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to get data from '{}'".format(worksheet_name))
            print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to connect with file_id '{}'".format(file_id))
        print(e)
    return df
```

the functions above are located in `mygsuite.py`.

Here's my source code that return error `InvalidJSONError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant`:

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())+'\\commons')
from mygsuite import *
from mypandas import *
from mystrings import *
import re
```

basic prerequisites to simplify my source code.

```
df = get_data_gsheet(file_id='1qDdOpKoYQ5R4VlP612_T845RJyQni2-V9IuJ676E07c'
                    ,worksheet_name='brand')
df.head()
```

Getting data from google sheet.

```
send_data_gsheet(file_id = '1tOXEnyNfEh9QC7f8FXJuEORIw4PpjR3sfp8tRmxmjT0'
                 ,worksheet_name='brand2'
                 ,df=df
                 ,mode='w')?
```

Objective:

1. i want to read and write from and to the same spreadsheet
2. Read from `brand` sheet,
3. write to `brand2` sheet. Create `brand2` sheet if it's not exist.

Comment: Can you provide the sample value of your dataframe for correctly replicating your current issue of `Out of range float values are not JSON compliant`?

Comment: @Tanaike done. pls advise

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your all values are texts?

Comment: yes they are all text @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your provided values of dataframe using your script, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue of `Out of range float values are not JSON compliant`. I confirmed that the values are put into the Spreadsheet without errors. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? For example, can you provide the script for creating your dataframe? By this, I would like to try to replicate your issue.

Comment: there. i've made changes. Thanks for helping out. Arigatou!

Comment: is there any certain libraries that i have to upgrade their version first?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your script using your showing sample value, no error occurs. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your current issue. The dataframe retrieved by `get_data_gsheet` can be correctly put into the Spreadsheet without errors. I apologize for this. When I could correctly replicate your current issue, I would like to think of a solution. By the way, about `is there any certain libraries that i have to upgrade their version first?`, how about updating gspread and gspread_dataframe?

Comment: NaN floats are not JSON compliant. Did you have any NaN values originally?

Comment: hi @MatthewStrawbridge just checked my dataframe and it has a blank cell. this is expected and i want this blank cell be sent to google sheet as well.

Comment: @Tanaike just checked my entire dataframe and it contains one blank cell. When i remove the blank cell from dataframe, the script above works. Thanks. Now am wondering how do i replace those `blank` with `""` or `''` so it comply with JSON format

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `just checked my entire dataframe and it contains one blank cell. When i remove the blank cell from dataframe, the script above works.`, I tested this situation. But, Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue of `Out of range float values are not JSON compliant`. Even when the empty cell is included in the dataframe, no error occurs. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.